# How to upload image to the server in android

Tags: android, image

i want to upload Image in Same Size choosed From Gallary.i.Uploaded to the server ..But Image is uploaded On Server like Compressed....like This Image Below
[image]

i want to upload Image in Same Size ...or how to set Cropped Intent In This Methode

here Is My Code To Adjust Image

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case 123987:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {

                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    Log.d("selectedImagePath", "selectedImagePath = " + selectedImagePath);

                    ParseImage _ParseImage = new ParseImage();
                    _ParseImage.activityContext = this;
                    _ParseImage.execute(selectedImagePath);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }

            break;

        case 1234:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {

                    final_bitmap = null;

                    String realPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName;

                    selectedImagePath = realPath;

                    new BitmapFactory();

                    Bitmap btmp = setBitmap(selectedImagePath);

                    /*String path = selectedImagePath.toLowerCase();
                    if (path.contains("dcim") && path.contains("camera")) {
                        btmp = RotateBitmap(btmp, 90);
                    }*/

                    int o_width = btmp.getWidth();
                    int o_height = btmp.getHeight();

                    // w=1840, h=3264
                    float large_image_ratio = 300.00f;

                    //Log.d("orignal_image", "orignal_image = " + o_width + " , " + o_height);
                    if (o_width > o_height) {

                        if (o_width >= large_image_ratio) {

                            float temp_w = (float)o_width/(float)large_image_ratio;
                            //int temp_h = o_height/large_image_ratio;

                            //Log.d("temp_w", "temp_w = " + temp_w);

                            int scales_width = (int) large_image_ratio;
                            int scales_height = (int) Math.round(o_height/temp_w);

                            //Log.d("scale_image-if", "scale_image-if = " + scales_width + " , " + scales_height);

                            final_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btmp, scales_width, scales_height, true);

                        } else {
                            final_bitmap = btmp;
                        }
                    } else {


                        if (o_height >= large_image_ratio) {

                            //int temp_w = o_width/large_image_ratio;
                            float temp_h = (float)o_height/(float)large_image_ratio;

                            //Log.d("temp_h", "temp_h = " + temp_h);

                            int scales_width = (int) Math.round(o_width/temp_h);
                            int scales_height = (int) large_image_ratio;

                            //Log.d("scale_image-else", "scale_image-else = " + scales_width + " , " + scales_height);

                            final_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btmp, scales_width, scales_height, true);
                        } else {
                            final_bitmap = btmp;
                        }

                    }

                    img.setImageBitmap(final_bitmap);

                    Image_into_Byte(final_bitmap);
                    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_upload.setEnabled(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public class ParseImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected Context activityContext;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                final_bitmap = null;

                this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activityContext, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
                //this.dialog.setTitle(title);
                this.dialog.setMessage("Loading Image");
                this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                this.dialog.show();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... image_path) {
            try {

                new BitmapFactory();

                Bitmap btmp = setBitmap(selectedImagePath);

                /*String path = selectedImagePath.toLowerCase();
                if (path.contains("dcim") && path.contains("camera")) {
                    btmp = RotateBitmap(btmp, 90);
                }*/

                int o_width = btmp.getWidth();
                int o_height = btmp.getHeight();

                // w=1840, h=3264
                float large_image_ratio = 300.00f;

                //Log.d("orignal_image", "orignal_image = " + o_width + " , " + o_height);
                if (o_width > o_height) {

                    if (o_width >= large_image_ratio) {

                        float temp_w = (float)o_width/(float)large_image_ratio;
                        //int temp_h = o_height/large_image_ratio;

                        //Log.d("temp_w", "temp_w = " + temp_w);

                        int scales_width = (int) large_image_ratio;
                        int scales_height = (int) Math.round(o_height/temp_w);

                        //Log.d("scale_image-if", "scale_image-if = " + scales_width + " , " + scales_height);

                        final_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btmp, scales_width, scales_height, true);

                    } else {
                        final_bitmap = btmp;
                    }
                } else {


                    if (o_height >= large_image_ratio) {

                        //float temp_w = o_width/large_image_ratio;
                        float temp_h = (float)o_height/(float)large_image_ratio;

                        //Log.d("temp_h", "temp_h = " + temp_h);

                        int scales_width = (int) Math.round(o_width/temp_h);
                        int scales_height = (int) Math.round(o_width/temp_h);

                        //Log.d("scale_image-else", "scale_image-else = " + scales_width + " , " + scales_height);

                        final_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btmp, scales_width, scales_height, true);
                    } else {
                        final_bitmap = btmp;
                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return "complete";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                this.dialog.cancel();
                SaveBitmap(final_bitmap);

                // final_bitmap
                img.setImageBitmap(final_bitmap);

                Image_into_Byte(final_bitmap);

                btn_upload.setEnabled(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then do not fiddle around with bitmaps and scales and resizing. It is just a file that you want to upload. Examples for uploading files you can find many on this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
// crop intent function

    public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri){
      //call the standard crop action intent 
      Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
      //indicate image type and Uri of image
      cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
      //set crop properties
      cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
      //indicate aspect of desired crop
      cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
      cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
      //indicate output X and Y
      cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
      cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
      //retrieve data on return
      cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
      //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
      startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
     }


get uri from gallery selected image

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else { 
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }


    use this function when get image  from gallery and camera :-

    // camera  on activityresult
    cropCapturedImage(Uri.fromFile(file));


    // gallery 

    cropCapturedImage(Uri.fromFile(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Base64` encoded string of `Bitmap` and send this image string to server via `NameValuePair` with `url`. Use `AsyncTask<...>` for uploading image like for example:

```
private class ImgUploadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    //do your stuff onPreExecute()       

   @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
           try
           {

            String imageDataString = null;

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost post = new  HttpPost(server_url);

            List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            imageDataString = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

            list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageDataString));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

            HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

            String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            Log.d("Response ", response);
          }
          catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;

        }
}

    //do your stuff onPostExecute()
```

After this you have to set your server side code, accept this `Base64 encoded` String and `decode` it on server side to get real image.

Comment: Base64 encoding an image is not the recommended way as it increases transfer volume by 30 %. Better send the file 'as is'.